# How to make python discord bot give role to pinged user

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So far I'd like to use such line but instead of message author I want the @username , the pinged person to get the role and I only want this command to be useable by people who have a specific role (For example admin role)

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content == 'give me admin':
        role = get(message.server.roles, name='Admin')
        await client.add_roles(message.author, role)
```

Comment: Can you share the code you've written to meet this new requirement? We're not going to write your code for you, but we can help if you show us what you've tried (as a [mre]) and where you're getting stuck - see [ask].

Answer (score 0):

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.guild is None:
        return
    admin_role = get(message.guild.roles, name="Admin")
    if admin_role not in message.author.roles:
        return
    try:
        member = message.mentions[0]
    except IndexError:
        return
    await member.add_roles(admin_role)
```

Admins can ping member for example `@User#1234` and the bot will add admin role to pinged member.